# How do I find the index of the maximum value in a list in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

It's easy enough to find the maximum value in a list in Perl 6:

```
> my @list = 1,4,9,7,3;
> say @list.max;
9
```

But if I want to find the *index* of the maximum entry, there doesn't seem to be an elegant way to do this.

```
> say (^@list).sort({ -@list[$_] })[0];
2
> say @list.pairs.sort(*.value).tail.key;
2
> say @list.first(@list.max, :k);
2
```

Those all work, but they're hardly elegant, let alone efficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

It'd be nice if `max` had `:k`, `:v` and `:kv` options, like for instance `first` has.
Of course, there might not *be* a unique index (for instance, in the case of `(1,4,9,7,9).max`, but then again, there might not be a unique *value* either:

```
> dd (1, 2.0, 2.0e0, 2).max;
2.0
> say <the quick brown fox>.max(*.chars);
quick
```

`max` already retrieves the *first* maximum value, so it would be perfectly reasonable to return the first *index* with `:k` (or `:kv`).

Comment: I just realized that *the* index of the maximum value might not exist, for instance if the list is `1,4,9,7,3,9,1`.  But still, a more elegant way to get *an* index would be welcome.

Comment: That's no different when returning the value. E.g. `dd (1, "2", 2).max(*.Int);` returns the Str value `"2"` instead of the Int value `2`, because it comes first. So `.max(:k)` returning the first matching index would be perfectly in line with existing behavior, and I'd consider the fact that the adverb is not supported here, an oversight.

Comment: Good point.  An even better example might be `dd(1, 2.0e0, 2.0, 2).max;`.

Comment: I added a final section about this to the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
@list.maxpairs
```

to get a list of all pairings of indices and maximal values or

```
@list.pairs.max(*.value).key
```

to get just a single index.

As far as I can see, both `maxpairs` and the ability to provide a transformation to `max` are still undocumented.

Comment: @mscha did you file doc issues for the undocumented things?